# Pytorch weights not updating.. sometimes

Tags: pytorch

Not sure what causes this, but sometimes I start training my neural net, and none of my weights update. This happens maybe 4 out of 5 times when I initialize my script. The other 1 time, it updates everything as expected and trains and predicts as expected. Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Started when I changed my loss function if that's relevant.
Here's the gross part of my training loop, let me know any other relevant code I should include.

```
def train(model, train_loader, test_loader, test_data, full_test, args, epochs, early_stop=5):
    t0 = time()
    optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)
    lr_decay = lr_scheduler.ExponentialLR(optimizer, gamma=args.lr_decay)
    best_val_acc, best_mae = 0, 500
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.train()
        ti = time()
        training_loss = 0.0
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_loader):
            x, y = Variable(x.cuda()), Variable(y.cuda())
            y_pred = model(x, y)
            loss = mae_loss(y, y_pred) + rmse_loss(y, y_pred)
            loss.backward()
            training_loss += loss.detach() * x.size(0)
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        lr_decay.step()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe by far the most likely issue is that your loss function is returning something incorrect. Try printing the first few losses to see what they are and ensure they are reasonable and the correct datatype and shape. One possible reason for the weights not updating if your losses seem ok is that the learning rate is too low for your losses and the weights are being changed by such a small amount that it is either rounded off or not apparent.

Comment: Thank you for this.
I've taken a look at my loss and everything seems to work as intended. I'll try out changing the learning rate to see if it affects anything, although would that explain why everything works as expected once in a while?

Comment: In addition to raising the learning rate, you may want to try messing with the initialization of the neural network. The learning rate could certainly explain why it works as expected occasionally, but this is probably best fixed by altering the initialization imo (but maybe someone else has better theoretical arguments for how to fix the problem).  On a separate note, what's the final layer of your neural network? Do you have an activation function on it?

Comment: Final layer is simply a Linear(256, 1) with a ReLU

Comment: I think your problem is actually likely to be a "dying ReLU". This may be resolved by a smaller learning rate (which makes the optimization less likely to go into the flat gradient portion of the ReLU).   If that doesn't work, you may want to change to a different activation function (on your entire network, not just the final layer). Also, if your targets are ever negative you probably want to remove the ReLU on the final layer (since ReLU can only be positive). Unless you want to constrain the output, the final layer is typically just a linear layer.

Comment: Also, just sort of a weird thing that probably isn't directly relevant. Your model seems to take x and y. I don't know exactly what you are doing but did you intend to feed the target into the model?

Comment: Thanks again Sam!
I am indeed only expecting positive values, which is why I added a ReLU to the final layer. And nice catch on the feeding of x and y haha, it was a typo from copy-pasting and re-editing before posting